# What happens if you call shift inside an anonymous sub?

Tags: perl, subroutine, anonymous

First off, apologies if this question is ill-posed; I don't actually know a heck of a lot of perl.

I'm trying to debug some existing code that is supposed to send grades from our online homework system called WeBWorK to an LMS. I'm running into a weird error where I think something isn't getting initialized right, or perhaps isn't the right class. I suspect that the problem might be here:

```
sub go {
    my $self = shift;
    my $r = $self->r;
    my $ce = $r->ce;

    # If grades are begin passed back to the lti then we peroidically
    # update all of the grades because things can get out of sync if
    # instructors add or modify sets.
    if ($ce->{LTIGradeMode}) {

      my $grader = WeBWorK::Authen::LTIAdvanced::SubmitGrade->new($r);

      my $post_connection_action = sub {
        my $grader = shift;

        # catch exceptions generated during the sending process
        my $result_message = eval { $grader->mass_update() };
        if ($@) {
          # add the die message to the result message
          $result_message .= "An error occurred while trying to update grades via LTI.\n"
        . "The error message is:\n\n$@\n\n";
          # and also write it to the apache log
          $r->log->error("An error occurred while trying to update grades via LTI: $@\n");
        }
      };
      if (MP2) {
        $r->connection->pool->cleanup_register($post_connection_action, $grader);
      } else {
        $r->post_connection($post_connection_action, $grader);
      }
    }
... # a bunch of other stuff happens in the "go" sub
```

I kinda suspect that the issue is with the `$grader` variable; in particular, I don't know what `my $grader = shift;` does inside an anonymous sub. Like, if the sub had a name, it would be more clear that `shift` is giving the first argument passed to the sub. But since it's anonymous, I don't know what it thinks its arguments are.

Further, I'm not really sure why that line is needed at all. Like, from my googling, I'm given to understand that the point of an anonymous sub is to keep all the variables from the surrounding environment in scope. So why do we need to redefine `$grader` inside the anonymous sub in the first place?

Thanks for helping a perl noob out! :)

Comment: Your anon sub isn't being called in the code you've shown - it's being assigned to `$post_connection_action` for use at some later point

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's nothing special about anon subs in this regard.

```
my $cr = sub {
   my $arg = shift;
   say $arg;
};

$cr->("foo");   # Prints "foo"
$cr->("bar");   # Prints "bar"
```

In your case, you pass `$post_connection_action` and `$grader` to `cleanup_register` or `post_connection` with the expectation that it will result in a call to `&$post_connection_action` with `$grader` as its first argument. Whether the expectation is correct or not depends on the implementation of `cleanup_register` and `post_connection`, of which I know nothing.

---

Note that another solution presents itself here. Subs have access to the lexicals that were in scope when the `sub` operator was evaluated.

```
my $prefix = "> ";
my $cr = sub {
   my $arg = shift;
   say "$prefix$arg";   # Captures $prefix from sub{} scope.
};

$cr->("foo");           # Prints "> foo"
```

The above is true even if captured lexicals would otherwise no longer exist by the time the sub is called.

```
my $cr;
{
   my $prefix = "> ";
   $cr = sub {
      my $arg = shift;
      say "$prefix$arg";   # Captures $prefix from sub{} scope.
   };
}                          # $prefix would normally stop existing here.

$cr->("foo");              # Prints "> foo"
```

That means you don't need to pass `$grader` as an argument. It can simply be *captured*. Just leave out `my $grader = shift;` (and don't pass `$grader` to 
`cleanup_register` or `post_connection`).

Comment: While your last statement is correct, it might be that the lexical `$grader` inside their anonymous sub is a different one than the one in `go`. The grader seems to depend on the state of `$self->r`. On the other hand, `$r` from outside the anonymous sub is used inside it, so that is unlikely.

Comment: @simbabque, Re "*It might be that the lexical `$grader` inside their anonymous sub is a different one than the one in `go`.*", No, it can't. The OP wants to use the `$grader` from outside the sub in the sub, and I showed them how they could do that.